# "Inconsistent digest name" errors with passlib and Flask Security

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, flask-security, passlib

I've got a GAE app built with Flask Security (which is awesome BTW).  Everything works great, but I'm getting errors like this in my GAE logs:

> /.../lib/passlib/crypto/digest.py:414: PasslibRuntimeWarning:
>   inconsistent digest name: 'md5' resolved to <built-in function new>,
>   which reports name as 'MD5'

Although the above message says it is a warning, GAE logs report it as an error.

I'd like to remove these errors from my GAE logs so I can focus on actual errors.

Is there a place where I can change `md5` to `MD5` to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop receiving those particular logs, the solution would be to use [exclusion filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#exclusion-filters). That way you can precisely determine which logs you don't want to see.

To do that, head to the Logging menu in the console and select "Resource usage". Inside that menu you will find an "Exclusion" tags. Once in that tab, select the "Create exclusion" option.

You will be redirected to the Logging page, with an "Exclusion editor" side menu. There you can define the parameters for your exclusion, such as the name, a description of the log entries you want to exclude (such as those where "inconsistent digest name MD5" appears) and the percent to exclude (if you want all of those log entries gone, use 100). After that, click "Create exclusion" and the log exclusion process will begin.

I hope this proves useful for you, however I wonder if the application is working correctly since you are getting that warning. Any clarification on that would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that GAE logging had exclusions.  I'd prefer to fix the cause rather than hide the symptom, but this could be a workaround.

Comment: I have reviewed the code of the passlib library you are using and I checked that the use of 'md5' in lower case is accepted by it. I am not 100% familiar with passlib, but I suspect there is some kind of issue with it. I would suggest you head to this [site](https://bitbucket.org/ecollins/passlib/issues) and check if there is an issue that could be associated with it. If not the case, feel free to file a new issue on that site so new improvements can be made on this library.